# How to get bar colors of multiple traces from bar chart?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I created a bar chart with multiple traces using a loop. The colors of each trace are assigned by plotly automatically. Now chart is done, how to get colors of all traces? I needed to assign these same colors to another scatter plot inside subplots to make color consistent.  Thank you so much for your help.

```
for i in range (10):
            fig.add_trace(
                    go.Bar(
                        x=weights_df_best.index,
                        y=weights_df_best[col].values,
                        name = col,
                        text=col,
                        hoverinfo='text',
                        legendgroup = '1',
                        offsetgroup=0,
                        ),
                    row=1,
                    col=1,
                         )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to put the colors in a list after you've produced a figure, just run:

```
colors = []
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: colors.append(t.marker.color))
```

If you use that approach in the complete snippet below, you'll get

```
['#636efa', '#EF553B', '#00cc96']
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.medals_long()
fig = px.bar(df, x="medal", y="count", color="nation", text_auto=True)

colors = []
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: colors.append(t.marker.color))
colors
```

Comment: Thank you vestland, that is awesome! I learnt a new trick today!

Comment: Hi Vestland, for go.Bar(), the returned colors is empty it is all [None, None, None]. anything wrong? Thanks

Comment: @roudan Great catch! A way around this could be to run `f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)` and then `f.for_each_trace(lambda t: colors.append(t.marker.color))`

Comment: @roudan We could dive deeper into the details here at a later time if this does not work out for you.

Comment: Thanks Vestland, the new code don't work either and I got an error of AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'full_figure_for_development'. Yes we can work on that later. Thanks for your help

Comment: @roudan Then you should definitely consider upgrading your Plotly version

Comment: @roudan Then you should definitely consider upgrading your Plotly version